# make div visible on h2 hover

Tags: html, css

I am currently learning CSS and am editing a stylesheet linked to the html on the CSS Zen Garden index file. I am trying to make the .summary div appear when hovering over the h2 header The Beauty of CSS Design but cant seem to make it work.
here is my css:

```
   .page-wrapper {
   margin:0 auto;
   width:50%;
   }

   .summary p{
   display:none;
   visibility:hidden;
   }

   .intro header h2:hover .summary  p{
   display:block;
   visibility:visible;
   }

   .summary p:hover{
   display:block;
   visibility:visible;
   }
```

Can someone please show me where I'm going wrong? If I just set it to .intro:hover it works but that will mean hovering over any element in intro. Btw, I realize I can just use .summary instead of .summary p. Thanks...

Comment: Can you post your HTML?

Comment: What you can do is `header:hover + .summary p { display:block; }`. The downside is it will be visible when the whole `<header>` is hovered, not just the `<h2>`. The upside is the `<header>` is a the preceding sibling of `.summary`, so you can use the adjacent sibling selector.

Comment: its exactly the same source html as that available on http://www.csszengarden.com

Comment: im still learning css so please forgive. i basically cant access summary thru the h2 unless they have the same parent right? Whatever selector i use for hover, i can only make changes to elements that are children of the selector? is there something we could do with of the css3 nth pseudoclasses?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is important to understand how CSS selectors work - most crucially, that they are not capable of traversing the DOM fluidly but can only be used to isolate descendants (nested children), or subsequent adjacents (elements on the same DOM level, which are placed after).

What this means is that you can only use CSS to select elements on a hierarchical basis dependant on DOM (HTML element) order.

ignoring the fact CSS is processed right to left, what this means is that as you move from left to right in your CSS selector, each rule following a space represents a subsequent *child element*.

The exception to this are the `~` and `+` adjacency selectors, which basically isolate subsequently occurring siblings of the type specified.

So, what does this mean for you?

What it means is that when you denote a hover 'event' in CSS, the rule you create can only relate to the element directly, a child of that element, a subsequent sibling, or a subsequent sibling of a child.

As such, unless your DIV is a child of your `h1` or appears immediately after it, you cannot create a CSS rule to make it appear on hover.

I would recommend you also take a look at [**the MDN article on selectors**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started/Selectors), which is a solid read

[Examples using the `+` adjacency selector](http://jsfiddle.net/fx9hE/)

[Examples using the `~` adjacency selector](http://jsfiddle.net/fx9hE/1/)

[Examples using a child selector](http://jsfiddle.net/fx9hE/3/)

Your current rule:

```
   .intro header h2:hover .summary  p{
      display:block;
      visibility:visible;
   }
```

Assumes your `p` is a child of `.summary` which is a child of `h2`:

```
<div class='intro'>
    <header>
        <h2>
        <span class='summary'><p></p></span>
    </h2>
    </header>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks that makes things a bit clearer. ill check out that article you posted.

Comment: also is it possible to maintain visibility as i move from the header block to the adjacent div block? I thought specifying a hover event for the div block to maintain visibility would work but the div block still becomes hidden as i move off the header block. im pretty sure i can do this with javascript but wondering if its possible thru css?